# How do I target a first-child that is visible (after children that are set to display:none), with only CSS

Tags: css

I need to target the first `<td>` element in a table row that is visible--meaning it does not have inline styling of `display:none`.

Here's the gotchyas:

- They are not always hidden
- Sometimes more than one is hidden.
- I can't edit the HTML or use javascript/jQuery--This needs to be a pure CSS solution (hopefully)

Here is a quick sample of what the code looks like:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="display:none">Header1</th>
            <th>Header2</th>
            <th>Header3</th>
            <th>Header4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="display:none">Body1</td>
            <td>Body2</td>
            <td>Body3</td>
            <td>Body4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried messing with something like this to no avail:

```
table > tbody > tr > td:first-of-type:not([style*="display:none"])
```

[Here's a fiddle to mess with](http://jsfiddle.net/zeroskillz/cpL7xu6j/)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK, not sure that is possible in pure CSS.

Comment: @D4V1D That's what I'm afraid of, but thought I would put it to all the people smarter than me on here.

Comment: Not being able to edit HTML or using JS is quite a tough requirement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your hidden elements are always at the beginning of the row, you can use the direct sibling selector for this `+`.

```css
td:first-child,
td[style*="none"] + td {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="display:none">Header1</th>
      <th>Header2</th>
      <th>Header3</th>
      <th>Header4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="display:none">Body1</td>
      <td>Body2</td>
      <td>Body3</td>
      <td>Body4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>Second</td>
      <td>Third</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="display:none">and</td>
      <td>here's</td>
      <td>an</td>
      <td style="display:none">edge</td>
      <td>case</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Dang Skippy! That did the trick. Works for single or multiples. Thanks!

Comment: And what about: `style="border: none"`? `none` is a valid property-value for several properties other than `display`.

Comment: Kind of an edge case. We can get verbose and use `td[style*="display:none"] + td` or `td[style*="display: none"] + td`, depending on how our style attribute is formatted.

Answer (score 2):

This will style anything that isn't "display:none", but undo that when it gets to a subsequent one that isn't "display:none".

```css
table > tbody > tr > td:not([style*="display:none"]) {
    color: red;
}
table > tbody > tr > td:not([style*="display:none"]) ~ td:not([style*="display:none"]) {
    color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="display:none">Header1</th>
      <th>Header2</th>
      <th>Header3</th>
      <th>Header4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="display:none">Body1</td>
      <td>Body2</td>
      <td>Body3</td>
      <td>Body4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>First</td>
      <td>Second</td>
      <td>Third</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```